# Allowing for a negative order, with Grand Total less than 0

Tags: checkout, grand-total

One of our clients has asked for the ability for its order entry personnel to submit orders with a negative order total. The application already allows negative line items, which works fine as long as the rest of the order makes a positive Grand Total.

It seems that Magento tries very hard to not have a negative order total. Looking at the collected totals shows that Magento will apply a gift card for the inverse amount. If I disable the gift card, then it applies Store Credit (even if credit does not exist). I suspect this is just a quirk (and possibly a red herring).

Can anyone help pinpoint where Magento forces 0 as its maximum Grand Total amount, and how we might go about fulfilling the request? I don't want to simply force-set the total, as I want Magento to calculate everything normally, just with the allowance of a negative Grand Total.

The spirit of the question is the technical feasibility, but once that is addressed, I'm interested in any 'gotchas' or thoughts that might dissuade the use of negative order totals from a non-technical standpoint.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want this?

Comment: @benmarks - As I know you know, sometimes 'that's what the client wants' trumps logic and reason. They want to give their sales folks (using a custom-built order form) full freedom on order creation and prices (which already works, even for negatively-priced line items - as long as the order total is above 0. This is just taking it a step further to allow the entire order to be negative if desired). Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you give a real world example where this would be useful?

Comment: How are you going to deal with credit memos?

Comment: @MaikelKoek - The client doesn't really do credit memos as it is, so I don't think that would have any impact.

Comment: I have a suspicion that there are *a lot* of places in the core that assume order totals are nonnegative, so I will defer to someone who has done this before.

Comment: @benmarks - I believe you might be right here. Magento Support recommended ECG, so it may not be as trivial as it originally sounded.

Comment: I don't know enough to know for sure, but my sixth sense (Magento-sense) is telling me that this would have non-obvious impacts later on.

Comment: @Morgon can you give us an scenario where an order would end up with a negative total? Maybe we can help come up with other ways to solve the problem that the client may not have thought of.

Comment: I am interested in finding out how items can have negative price when Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice ends with `return max(0, $finalPrice);` ?

Comment: The multiple totals models that magento uses are a slippery slope to go down. I highly recommend not doing it this way. I have seen extensions that allow order editing, and that may help, but I have never used one so no recommendation unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a very risky decision. If you implemented it you would need to override too much of the core, making the site extremely difficult to upgrade and support.

Performing a search in the Magento core for `max(0` returns results in the following areas:

- `Enterprise_CustomerBalance_Model_Observer::creditmemoDataImport()`
- `Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Catalog_Product_Price_Giftcard::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped_Price::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_CatalogRule_Helper_Data::calcPriceRule()`
- `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Price::getFinalPrice()`
- `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process()`
- `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax::_initSubtotal()`
- `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax (multiple uses)`

And many more in templates in the adminhtml and frontend areas. You may need to rewrite many of these models to achieve the desired functionality.

You may want to consider the alternatives below:

- Give the sales people logins to the Magento admin area and allow them to create orders from there - full control over item pricing etc
- Use store credit if the customer should be getting credit back (I assume this is what an order with negative total would be for?)

If you provide a scenario where an order would end with a negative total, and also the reasoning behind it then the community will be able to give you a better answer. It's hard to solve a problem like this until you understand the business value behind the decision.

Comment: Good ans. I like that :)